Laravel fortify not sending the correct url in email verification
I'm trying to setup laravel fortify, so far I have been able to setup the register part however I encountered a strange error. my APP_URL is set to http://127.0.0.1:8000 however for some reason laravel fortify email verification is sending me an email with localhost, as seen in the image below:

As a result I get invalid signature since it doesn't match my APP_URL, how can one go about fixing this? I have changed the APP_URL in my .env to http://127.0.0.1:8000 to no avail.
